# Why say "ça fait bien longtemps", not "ça ferait bien longtemps", when describing a hypothetical situation?

Tags: temps-grammatical, conditions

> Si le but de ces gens **était** d’empêcher leur mariage coûte que coûte, ça **fait** bien longtemps déjà que le couple **devrait** se trouver six pieds sous terre...

In describing this hypothetical situation, I wonder why "fait" does not need to take the form of Conditionnel Présent "ferait" –  with only "devrait" in the subordinate clause being in Conditionnel.

> = "If they really wanted to sabotage their marriage, the couple would have been six feet under for a long time now..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overlooking (clearly because there's only two verbs in the English sentence) the fact the amount of elapsed time is the only part of the French sentence which is not a supposition of some sort.

Comment: To enlight the point, here is a similar example: "Si le but de ces gens était d’empêcher leur mariage coûte que coûte, il est certain que le couple devrait se trouver six pieds sous terre" but not "il serait certain" because certainty is above/not related to the condition itself.

Comment: Hi. Is it incorrect to use the past conditional here? : "... ça fait bien longtemps déjà que le couple ***se serait trouvé*** six pieds sous terre..." Also to @lemon

Comment: @Alone-zee, grammatically it is correct but semantically it is probably not here: "... se serait trouvé (une ou plusieur fois, ponctuellement)..." and "... se trouverait (toujours, depuis, encore)..." (same for "devrait se trouver")